# HTML5 & CSS: Formatting anchors, <header>-wide

Tags: css, html, header, anchor

I encountered a peculiar CSS formatting problem when I changed a `<div id="header">` block to HTML5's `<header>` block. Basically, I want links within the `<header>` block to be of a certain colour and to not get any decoration.

The relevant HTML and CSS codes look as follows:

```
<!-- HTML5 code -->
<header>
    <h1>
        <a href="#">Link text</a>
    </h1>
</header>

/* CSS code */
header a {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

The output I see (using **Firefox 20.0** with Ubuntu 12.04) is as if the CSS code fragment above does not exist.

Adding something like `class="hdr"` to the anchor block and changing the CSS rule to `a.hdr` works. Changing back to `<div id="header">` and `#header a` also works. Still, I don't see why just using `<header>` and a corresponding rule fails, and it strikes me as the "correct" approach.

An initial search for a solution led me, among other links, to this [link](http://boblet.tumblr.com/post/178852468/block-level-links) (I had the `<h1>` block nested within the `<a>` block, initially), but using a `<div>` wrapper didn't work either.

Comment: Works for me in Chrome. Can't look at FF now (new system I'm building) but I'm sure it works there, too.

Comment: This may be a [specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Specificity) issue. What CSS code are you using to style your other anchor links?

Comment: Have you checked in the Inspector, to see if the styles really aren't being applied, or if they're just being overridden by something more specific?

Comment: @Blazemonger It seems you're right on the money! In my CSS file, before the `header a {...}` rule I set two rules `a:visited {...}` and `a:hover {...}`; if I comment them out, then the header anchor appears the way I want it to. I thought that the `[block] a` rule would override universal attribute rules, but I was apparently wrong. Is there any way to have my `header a {...}` inherit its action to its sub-rules/attributes, rather than specifying rules `header a:visited {...}`, etc, explicitly? (Pardon my likely erroneous terminology.)

Comment: @crimson_penguin Perhaps surprisingly, the styles show up exactly as I'd want them to in the Element Inspector. I can see a universal `a {...}` rule be overridden by `header a {...}`, but the `a:hover {...}` and `a:visited {...}` rules, which do not show up in the Inspector, seem to prevail.

Comment: There's two ways to fix specificity: the wrong way, which is to slap `!important` on any style you want to win out, and the right way, which is to make one rule more specific than the others. Read the link I provided for guidelines on doing it the right way.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense then. Pseudo-classes have a higher specificity value; @Blazemonger's link has the list. What you can do is define them all at once, like this: `header a, header a:hover, header a:visited { ... }`. Not as nice as it could be, but it could be worse. You might also want to look into using something like http://sass-lang.com

Comment: @Blazemonger's link (and another link therein) helped quite a bit, although it wasn't perfectly clear to me in the beginning. Indeed, the pseudo-class `a:visited` rule has a specificity of 11, whereas `header a` has a specificity of 2, hence the problem. And I found that there's another way of writing the same thing, with a high specificity: `header a:nth-child(n)`. This is equivalent to `header a` (since `nth-child(n)` selects all children) but has a specificity of 12---and I don't need to add all `a:[hover/link/visited]` clauses.
@Blazemonger, do you want to post an answer or shall I?

Answer (score 0):

Try being more specific.

```
<header class="main-header">

    <a href="#"><h1>Link Text</h1></a>

</header> <!-- .main-header -->


.main-header a {
    color: green;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Comment: Indeed, this works, but I wanted to avoid adding a superfluous class that's essentially synonymous to the `<header>` block. In fact, I found a way to do this with pseudo-classes, which only introduces a change in the CSS file. (See comment in my question, for now.)

Comment: Yeah. You shouldn't have to use a class for the header. I am just in the practice of putting the anchor tag outside of the element now. That is indeed weird that it is not working for you. Must those styles that are in your framework or reset or something. The syntax is correct.

Answer (score 0):

using

```
header h1 a {}
```

as your selector should fix your specificity issue

Else if your style is getting overridden once it's become visited (by the a:visited selector) you can write a style of equal specificity but it'll override the other rule because it's later in the cascade

```
header a:visited {}
```

Just make it come later in the stylesheet

BTW, sorry had to post an answer as I can't comment yet